# Finding equation with given solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I was wondering if there was a way to find the equation with given solution. I don't mean easy ones like quadratic equations... for example I had to do this exercises:

> 

Given the solution $ \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt{2}$ determine the minimal polynomial on $Q(\sqrt{2})$ and $Q$.

> 

I know that the first polynomial has third degree instead the second sixth degree. I tried to solve it (case $Q(\sqrt{2})$) writing the third power of the given solution and look how I could "transform " what I obtained in order to find the polynomial... you understand that it is a very slow way to resolve the exercise. Have you got some advices to make it easier?
Thanks!

Comment: "Given the solution..." The solution **to what**?

Comment: @DonAntonio to the polynomial that I have to find... maybe I haven't explained well my doubt... I have to find the minimal polynomial on $Q$ and $Q(\sqrt{2})$. I know that polynomial has $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt{2}$ as a solution. I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: Oh, I see. You use "solution" here meaning "a root"...Fine.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$x=\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt2\implies(x-\sqrt2)^3=2\implies x^3-3\sqrt2\,x^2+6x-2(\sqrt2+1)=0$$

So $\;\sqrt[3]2+2\;$ is a root of $\;f(t)=t^3-2\sqrt2\,t^2+6t-2(\sqrt2+1)\in\Bbb Q[t]\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Let $x= \sqrt[3]{2}+ \sqrt{2}$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-\sqrt[3]{2})^2=2 \\
x^2-2 = 2 \sqrt[3]{2}x-2^{2/3} \\
(x^2-2)^3= 16x^3-4-12x \underbrace{(2 \sqrt[3]{2}x-2^{2/3})}_{=x^2-2 } 
\end{eqnarray*}
So a polynomial that $x$ satisfies is $x^6-6x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24x-4=0$.

Comment: Why $2\sqrt{2}x - 2^{2/3}$ is equal to $x^2 -2$ ?

Comment: It is the equation above.

Comment: Yes but the equation above is : $2^{2\3}+2*2^{5\6} = x^2 -2$

Comment: It is a pretty standard piece of algebra ... If $x=\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}$ then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^3=a+b+ 3 \sqrt[3]{ab} \underbrace{ (\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b})}_{=x} 
\end{eqnarray*}